# Infinite loop on submit button

Tags: php, html

I have a problem with an infinite loop as the title says. I have this written in HTML:

```
<form action="add_to_current_playlist.php" method="post">
  <input type="submit" value="Add to current playlist"></input>
  <br>
</form>
```

and in `add_to_current_playlist.php` I have this at the end:

```
$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$sec = "0";
header("Refresh: $sec; url=$page");
include("music.html")
```

I am using this so that my php file runs but refreshes the page with the newly generated results.  The problem is that the submit button acts like it is stuck down (stuck submitting).  When I click to submit it will refresh the music.html page over and over. Is there a way to stop the loop or to "`unsubmit`" the button from the php page?  Maybe a better page refresh method?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `header("Refresh: $sec; url=$page");` this will redirect to itself infinitely.

Comment: How do I run my .php file then without leaving the music.html page?

Comment: You will have to learn JQuery/AJAX to make requests without leaving the page.

Comment: You could wrap it in an isset -> `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){  unset($_POST['submit']); /* your code here */ }`. This way it only does it the first time, and not infinitely as you unset the condition.

Comment: I tried what you said Sean but it still loops repeatedly

Comment: To use Sean's method, you would need to add a name to the submit button. `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add to current playlist"></input>`. You could also just use `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "POST")`.

Comment: @DaveChen, true my comment was just meant as an example as the OP did not have `name="submit` in the input. Your suggestion would be better.

Comment: I don't know what I am doing wrong still. Even doing it those ways still results in the page being refreshed many times in a row :/